# Oauth query - using access token and secret

Tags: c#, java

I am developing an application based on google Oauth. Now my all authentications are done. Even I have now the access token and secret. Now I dont know how to use this access token and secret. 
Please I really need Help on this. I have already done the hard work which is getting access token and secret. Only need to know how to use this token and secret to call an api.

Comment: Perhaps you should show what you've done to try and resolve this (eg what documentation you've looked at, where you're stuck, etc), rather than just adding 'please help'

Comment: Hi, thanks. After struggling 5 days I figured out how to get access token and secret from freelancer api sandbox. And now I dont know how to use this oauth to make a api call.

Answer (score 2):

To use the access key/secret you

1. set inputparameters for the google client service
2. create a token using the access key and secret, and the inputparameters
3. set the token in the google client service

In Python, using the gdata library:

```
    self.gd_client.SetOAuthInputParameters(
        gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1,
        self.consumer_key, consumer_secret=self.consumer_secret)
    oauth_input_params = gdata.auth.OAuthInputParams(
        gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1,
        self.consumer_key, consumer_secret=self.consumer_secret)
    oauth_token = gdata.auth.OAuthToken(key=access_key,
                                        secret=access_secret,
                                        scopes=gdata.gauth.AUTH_SCOPES,
                                        oauth_input_params=oauth_input_params)
    self.gd_client.SetOAuthToken(oauth_token)
```

After that you can call the service methods to retrieve the data.

Nico